# Login as Administrator on Windows OEM installation

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have just installed Windows 7 Ultimate on an used laptop I'm about to sell. The laptop needs to have a few drivers installed to work properly, but I don't want to create any user account on it. I want that when the person first turns on the laptop, it will still come up with the "Set Up Windows" pop up, as the one shown below:

[image]

So, how can I log in to the Administrator account to install those drivers? Or if there are any other possible way to install them, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create the account, enable the default Administrator account, install the drivers, then delete the user account you created.  Let the new owner create their own user account with the Administrator account.  You could also just use SysPrep.

Comment: Is it a better option then to just record the drivers on a CD and send it together with the laptop? That way the new owner will still have the opportunity to pick a computer name and a new user account.

Comment: You want my opionion?  I personally, would leave it up entirely, up to the buyer to locate the drivers for the device.  The only thing he is buying is the device itself and the license for Windows that comes with it.  I personally wouldn't even install it for him.

Comment: Agreed with Ramhound.

Comment: Well, seems fair enough for me. Thanks for the opinion then :)

Comment: @BrunoFinger If you're selling the machine on something like Ebay where you are rated, it may be best to go the extra mile and install the drivers. Also, you never know when word of mouth may help you sell more stuff. Goodwill is hard to buy and if you can get it with 15 minutes of your time, it may be well worth it.

Comment: @Trav Thanks. Yes, I'm selling it on a local website with rating system similar to eBay. I guess you're right. I wouldn't like to have to go after drivers after I buy a computer, although for me it wouldn't really be a problem, some users may simply not know how to do it. Your answer seems to satisfy the question, I'll try it out and mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll want to do is put the machine in the Out of the Box Experience state after you install drivers and make any other changes you need. Do the following:

1. Go ahead and make the account (give it a name like `OEM User` that your buyer most likely won't use), login, and install the drivers. Make sure you are totally finished installing anything or making changes to the system.
2. Click Start and enter the following in the Search box: `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe`
3. Choose **Enter System Out-Of-Box Experience (OOBE)** from the System Cleanup Action box.
4. *Very Important:* Uncheck the **Generalize** box. You do not need to Generalize the system, since you are not making an image but only want the New Account prompts to pop up.
5. Click OK.

Comment: This is a nice tool in W7, used so little by so many....

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for really seems to be [Audit Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd799305). Ctrl+Shift+F3 on the screen you posted will log you in as Administrator and let you customize the system before eventually running Sysprep to reseal the system and bring the new user to the page you show.